# getUserMedia() on Android device returns wrong default audio input

Tags: android, cordova, webrtc, getusermedia, crosswalk

On my HTC One (first model), calling getUserMedia() with {audio:true} activates the wrong audio input device. The remote partner cannot hear anything if I talk into the microphone. The audio track's label is empty in this case.

If I set the audio device manually to one of the device ids reported by enumerateDevices(), it works. In this case, the audio track's label shows something like "Headset earpiece", which is funny as this is the microphone. If I chose the other (non-default) device, its label is "Speakerphone". This one does *not* work, which is quite counter-intuitive.

Unfortunately, I have no way to tell in advance which one is the right audio input to select it correctly. All device labels are empty in this case, I only get cryptic device ids. In total, 3 audio devices are returned, one has the id "default" (but this is the wrong one).

What may cause this misbehaviour, and how might I fix it?

(I am using the latest Crosswalk in an Cordova app, if that matters.)

Comment: I am in and out working on this issue...do you have any updates on this?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not.